# Sort and merge a multidimensional array by common value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and I'm trying to sort it by common value of one particular key, **name** in my case.

I already tried using a foreach to loop into the array, or using usort, but I just can't find the way to do it.

Notice how the values of the "Diamètre" key are merged into an array in the final result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0]  => Array
                (
                    [name]  => Diamètre
                    [value]  => 5                   
                )

            [1]  => Array
                (
                    [name]  => Force
                    [value]  => 30                  
                )

        )

    [1]  => Array
         (

            [0]  => Array
                (
                    [name]  => Force
                    [value]  => 20             
                )

            [1]  => Array
                (
                    [name]  => Poids
                    [value]  => 50         
                )
          )
     [2]  => Array
         (
            [0]  => Array
                (
                    [name]  => Diamètre
                    [value]  => 40
                )

            [1]  => Array
                (
                    [name]  => Largeur
                    [value]  => 40
                )

          )
)
```

Expected result :

```
Array
(

            [0]  => Array
                (
                    [name]  => Diamètre
                    [value]  => Array (5, 40)                                                              
                )

            [1]  => Array
                (
                    [name]  => Force
                    [value]  => Array (30, 20)               
                )

             [2]  => Array
                 (
                    [name]  => Poids
                    [value]  => 50        
                 ) 

             [3]  => Array
               (
                    [name]  => Largeur
                    [value]  => 40
                )     
)
```

Comment: "I already tried many things" Show these things that you've tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton There seem to be a "merge the array when collisons occurs" here that I don't see in that duplicate target though.

Comment: @Marco is it important that the values in "Poids" and "Largeur" stay as single value, instead of arrays containing only one value?

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier no it's not important

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier The requirements for that weren't even mentioned in the question

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I think they are very much mentioned when you actually read the desired output. Desired output being one of the things we ask of askers, it'd be great if you read it.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Yes, it's in the output but the question itself does not mention this requirement or detail at all when and where it merges. Either way your right though it's not a correct target.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton good point, I was on the lucky side when adding it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of:

```
$result = [];

foreach($array1 as $array2) {
    foreach($array2 as $item) {

        if(array_key_exists($item['name'], $result)) {
            $newItem = $result[$item['name']];

            $valueArray = (array) $item['value'];
            $newValueArray = (array) $newItem['value'];

            $newItem['value'] = array_merge($valueArray, $newValueArray);
        } else {
            $newItem = $item;
        }

            $result[$item['name']] = $newItem;
    }
}

// In case you don't want an associative array.
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: Here the result @Mkk : Array ( [Diamètre] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [Force] => Array ( [0] => 30 ) [Poids] => Array ( [0] => 50) )